# How to extract <style> content from HTML file in Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, file

I've copied contents from a index.html file. Now I just want to copy everything that's inside the style tags. How can I do this?

```
 file = File.open("filepath/index.html", "rb")
 @html_file_contents = file.read  //@html_file_contents has raw html from which I need to extract style tag contents.
```

Comment: Use a HTML parser like [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/)

Comment: ...And I know you didn't suggest this (which is a rare relief!), but [**don't** use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1954610).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Nokogiri`](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) gem

```
require 'nokogiri'

file = File.open("filepath/index.html", "rb")
page = Nokogiri::HTML(file.read)
first_style_tag = page.css('style')[0]
puts first_style_tag.text
```

see this tutorial http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/

Not tested, please try it out

Comment: With a small edit it worked. Thanks!
  index_html = file.read
  page = Nokogiri::HTML(index_html)
  css_styles = page.css('style')[0]